# Which of the following is true about lebesgue measure

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

Which of the following is true?

1) $\{ x\in  \mathbb{R}: x^6-6x^4 \text{ is irrational}\}$ is a Lebesgue-measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$

2) If $A$ is a lebesgue measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $B$  is a lebesgue non-measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $B \subset A$, then it is necessary that $m^*(A\setminus B)>0$

3) If $A$ and $B$ are disjoint subset of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $A$ is lebesgue measurable and $B$ is a lebesgue non-measurable, then it is possible that $m^*(A \cup B)< m^*(A)+m^*(B)$

Remarks:

1) Can we think given set as inverse image of continuous function where $f(x)=x^6-6x^4$, Please help

3) my intuition says is not true for non-measurability of $B$ , Please help

I have no idea about 2, please help

Comment: For $1$ indeed. With the $f$ you defined, the set in $1$ is nothing else than $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q})$.

Comment: I don't understand how the last one makes sense. How one defines the measure of a non-measurable set?

Comment: I think 3 is false and relies on the fact that $A^c$ is measurable when $A$ is measurable.

Comment: @Shashi. It's an [outer measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_measure) which is defined for all sets. A set $E \subseteq \mathbb R$ is called *measurable* if for every $A \subseteq \mathbb R$ the following equality is satisfied:
$$\mu^*(A) = \mu^*(A \cap E) + \mu^*(A \cap E^c),$$
where $E^c$ is the complement of $E.$

Comment: @md2perpe Oh I thought $m^*$ was the Lebesgue measure.  So it is not the Lebesgue measure?

Comment: @Shashi. No, $m$ is the Lebesgue measure and $m^*$ the outer measure used to define the Lebesgue measure. In the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure) they are denoted with $\lambda$ and $\lambda^*$ respectively.

Comment: @md2perpe yes many thanks!!!

Comment: what about 2 and 3

Comment: @ md2perpe, please help on 2 and 3

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert, but I think that I found a proof of 2 today.

Assume that $A$ is measurable, $B \subseteq A$ is not measurable, and $m^*(A \setminus B) = 0.$ If I get it correctly then all $m^*$-null sets are $m$-measurable and (obviously) are $m$-null. Thus $A \setminus B$ is measurable. This however implies that $B = A \setminus (A \setminus B)$ is measurable. Contradiction! Thus, $m^*(A \setminus B) > 0.$